# Create a pie chart with chartjs package in R

Tags: r, chart.js

I would like to build a dynamic pie chart with chartjs packages.
I found on http://tutuchan.github.io/chartjs/pie_chart.html  a simple code but it doesn't work for me.

When I used the following code :

```
library(chartjs)
chartjs(mtcars[1:6,], mpg, qsec) %>% 
  cjsPie
```

I get :

> chartjs(mtcars[1:6, ], mpg, qsec) : object 'qsec' not found

Anybody have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on https://github.com/Tutuchan/chartjs/commit/4066541ada0cd0b11f49608af3c2357bc44b8bc6#diff-60bb2b0586d33a8a794dc7ab45e0302bR12

```
library(chartjs)
chartjs(height = "500px") %>% 
  cjsPie(labels = mtcars[1:6,]) %>%
  cjsSeries(data = c(1:6))
```

[image]